# PHP DOM parse get button value value

Tags: php

I am trying to get the value `HELLO WORLD` of the button `<button class="btn btn-secondary sizes-input">HELLO WORLD</button>`
I tried using NodeValue or textContent but it didn't work.

```
 $htmlDetail=file_get_contents_curl("http://www.url.com/" . $href);
        $docDetail=new DOMDocument();
        $docDetail->loadHTML($htmlDetail);            
        $nodes=$docDetail->getElementsByTagName("button");
        foreach($nodes as $button){
            $attribute=$button->getAttribute("class");
            if($attribute=="btn btn-secondary sizes-input"){
                $btn=$button->nodeValue;
                $content=$button->textContent;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The attribute name on your sample and the one on your code are clearly different. I also suggest you to use `View Source Code` instead of the developer's tool or firebug as they render dynamic content which would be different from the source code.

Comment: Well, can you show us what you actually have? This should work as it is.

Comment: just a tip: try to use `strpos` instead

Comment: Works fine for me with both `nodeValue` und `textContent`. Make sure the HTML is actually being fetched properly from the URL. Or could it be that you're just trying to access `$btn` and `$content` from outside the loop? Because they're out of scope as soon as the loop ends unless you initiate them before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

First include the simple dom parser in your file.and then 
Try This:

```
$toGet = "http://www.url.com";
        $innerHtmlPage = file_get_html($toGet);
        if ($innerHtmlPage->find('body class')) {
        foreach ($innerHtmlPage->find('btn btn-secondary sizes-input') as $innerelement) {
            $content = $innerelement->plaintext;
        }
        }
```